# How do I add images to a carousel slider on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

I am new to coding, and I am trying to add a carousel to my homepage on Wordpress. Where do I save the images to be used in my carousel?
I would appreciate any help-thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to code the carousel yourself? There are a lot of plugins that will help you realize this.

Comment: I need to use code, no plugins!

Comment: If you've made any progress yourself, could you please post the code? This will greatly help us help you.

Comment: The code I am using is on this page http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp. The problem I have is, I am not sure where I save my images for it to show up

Comment: You have multiple options for this, you can host them on an online platform like "imgur" (no advertisement intended) or host them locally. If you do host them locally, make sure the path to the images is correct.

Comment: I am working with modifying a wordpress theme, how do I know where to save the images to in order to be able to use it effectively in my carousel?

Comment: Are you hosting the wordpress instance yourself or is it on a website online?

Comment: I am not hosting it myself, it being hosted ona  third party domain

Comment: Have you got access to the FTP of this domain?

Comment: Yes I have access to the FTP

Comment: You should upload the images you want to have in your carousel to the wordpress folder, there should be a wp-images if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think You try this plugin

[https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-slider-with-lightbox/screenshots/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-slider-with-lightbox/)

Try this plugin

Please read description carefully after use...it works for me. I hope this plugin also work for you.

Comment: Thank you Krunal, unfortunately I can't use a plugin- but rather code it.

Comment: i try my best to give solution